# Mac won't detect Serial Port for Leonardo

Tags: serial, arduino-leonardo, usb, mac-os

***EDIT:*** *The problem was the cable I was using (see answer below).*

---

I have a MacBook Pro running OS X Yosemite (10.10.1). I connected my Arduino Leonardo to my computer for the first time today (using a Micro USB to USB cable), but my computer isn't detecting it.

When I opened the Arduino IDE I selected Tools > Board > "Arduino Leonardo", but when I try to choose a Serial Port the only options are:

- /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
- /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
- /dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem
- /dev/cu.Bluetooth-Modem

[image: screenshot of available serial ports]

I have tried closing and relaunching the Arduino IDE, disconnecting and reconnecting my Arduino Leonardo, and restarting my computer, but I still only see the four Bluetooth ports.

System Information (aka System Profiler) doesn't show anything connected to any of my USB ports.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried another cable? Another computer?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I don't have any other Micro USB cables, but I tried it with my roomate's PC (Windows 7) and it didn't work there either. Then I realized that the cable I have is only for charging Android phones. It doesn't do any data transfer. I'm going to buy a new cable. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem but its not cable's fault. I have dual boot with windows and on windows everything works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@IgnacioVazquez-Abrams's comment made me realize that the problem was the Micro USB cable I was using. It gave the Arduino 5V power from my computer, but didn't support any data connection. I'm buying a new cable.